# get logged in Userid from Session in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to show these results on the user dashboard automatically, when user logs in to their dashboard, I want this query to run and show them the statistics for their user id. Please suggest how to do this. How to get logged in userid, working code for the statistics is posted below.

```
<?php 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
          tblclients.userid as client_id, 
          tblclients.company as company_name, 
            IFNULL(tblinvoices.total, 0) AS total_amount, 
              IFNULL(tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount, 0) AS paid_amount, 
                ( IFNULL(tblinvoices.total, 0) - IFNULL(tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount, 0)) AS amount_due 
            FROM 
            tblclients 
            LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.userid = tblinvoices.clientid 
            LEFT JOIN tblinvoicepaymentrecords ON tblinvoices.id = tblinvoicepaymentrecords.invoiceid
            WHERE tblclients.userid = 1");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)

{
      echo $row['total_amount'] . " " . $row['paid_amount'] . " " .$row['amount_due']; 
      echo "<br />";
      }
?>
```

after checking this code :

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
```

I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1504507372
    [client_user_id] => 1
    [contact_user_id] => 1
    [client_logged_in] => 1
    [red_url] => https://www.trisuka.com/crm/admin
)
```

Comment: Anybody, Please help out.

Comment: How to get logged in userid  ? ? You must have stored it in codeigniter session ? ?

Comment: @Root Ingenious : Thanks you are here buddy, Yes i have stored, but as u can see above code, one is the complete sqlquery given by you only,, how i will apply the user id in select statement,, right now it is manual userid=1 .. or do i have to fetch all the user id's from db and in -result, will have to filter using session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all i would suggest you to check all the session data in your controller using

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
```

try to print and check what is the key you have store in the session to store the user id.

suppose you have key available in the array like `userId` then
You can get the session data using the below line

```
$userId = $this->session->userdata('client_user_id');
```

But make sure you have key available in session named "client_user_id".

and once you get the `$userId` form the session you can concat it to the query like this.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
          tblclients.userid as client_id, 
          tblclients.company as company_name, 
            IFNULL(tblinvoices.total, 0) AS total_amount, 
              IFNULL(tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount, 0) AS paid_amount, 
                ( IFNULL(tblinvoices.total, 0) - IFNULL(tblinvoicepaymentrecords.amount, 0)) AS amount_due 
            FROM 
            tblclients 
            LEFT JOIN tblinvoices ON tblclients.userid = tblinvoices.clientid 
            LEFT JOIN tblinvoicepaymentrecords ON tblinvoices.id = tblinvoicepaymentrecords.invoiceid
            WHERE tblclients.userid = '".$userId."' ");
```

Comment: hey dear Punit, i checked the session data, as you mentioned above and the result i have posted in question ( updated ).

Comment: @GauravSingh , i have updated the answer.. try `$userId = $this->session->userdata('client_user_id');` and you will get the logged in client.